# Microsoft Dynamics 365 (on-premise v8.2) how enable subarea button for ISH for custom role?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365, interactive-service-hub

Microsoft Dynamics 365 Interactive Service Hub (ISH) button (on area Settings, subarea Apps) 
visible for  Service Manager, System Administrator, or System Customizer roles ([article on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt812236.aspx#bkmk_Support)  ).

How can I make this button visible for other roles?

I have CRM version 8.2 , onpremise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referred in the Technet article, those button & link is available only for certain roles by OOB.

But you can use the 3rd option, by referring the direct link for `engagementhub.aspx` in sitemap for any roles.

[image]

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/250460)